# Generic registration in Windsor with UsingFactoryMethod

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

We currently have code that looks something like below, with a factory being injected in to a lot of classes, which then call the factory to get an instance of what they want.

```
public class Service
{
     public Service(IFactory factory)
     {
          _car = factory.GetCar<Entity>();
     }
}

public class Car : ICar
{
}

public interface IFactory
{
    ICar<TEntity> GetCar<TEntity>();

    IBoat<TEntity> GetBoat<TEntity>();
}

public class Factory : IFactory
{
    ConnectionDetails _connectionDetails;    

    public Factory(ConnectionDetails connectionDetails)
    {
        _connectionDetails = connectionDetails;
    }

    TEntity GetCar<TEntity>()
    {
        var car = new Car<TEntity>(_connectionDetails);
        car.Initialize();
        return car;
    }
}
```

I was hoping to be able to create a solution that would allow for request a dependency directly on the `Car<TEntity>` without needing to go through the factory first.

Below is an example of installing for a single `TEntity`, but how would I set this up to be generic?

I've tried using open generics, but I can't see how I can get the correct return type out of `.UsingFactoryMethod()`.

I know I can get the `RequestedType` out of the `CreationContext`, but I don't see how I can use that to solve this problem.

```
public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
                    Component.For<ICar<TEntity>>().UsingFactoryMethod(
                        kernel =>
                        {
                            var factory = kernel.Resolve<IFactory>();
                            return factory.GetCar<TEntity>();
                        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I find that factories mixed with dependency injection can be a bit of anti-pattern, since it hides implementation/creation details somewhere other than the object graph root.  In addition, when mixing the two it becomes unclear who ultimately has the responsibility for creating and maintaining objects and their lifecycles.

I'd recommend you move to allowing the container to fully handle creation details based on common base interfaces/classes.

```
void Main()
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Install(new Installer());

    var car = container.Resolve<Car>();
    car.Dump();
}

public class Service
{
    private ICar<CarEntity> _car;

    public Service(ICar<CarEntity> car)
    {
        _car = car;
    }
}

public class TEntity { }
public class CarEntity : TEntity { }
public class BoatEntity : TEntity { }

public interface ICreatable { }
public interface ICar<TEntity> : ICreatable { }

public class Car : ICar<TEntity> 
{
    private ConnectionDetails _connectionDetails;

    public Car(ConnectionDetails connectionDetails)
    {
        _connectionDetails = connectionDetails; 
        Initialize();
    }

    public void Initialize() {}
}

public class ConnectionDetails { }

public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<ConnectionDetails>()
                     .ImplementedBy<ConnectionDetails>());

        container.Register(
            Classes.FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
                .BasedOn(typeof(ICreatable))
                .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
                .WithServiceSelf()
                .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't really thought of changing the behaviour of those classes, but that makes sense. I should be able to skip out the factory all together. I'll give it a go.

Comment: You'll find this makes it much easier to scale as you add new types as well, since you are no longer dependent on modifying your factory to handle creation details.

Comment: This is working well now, I just hadn't thought about restructuring quite so deep. The factory already existed, I hadn't considered obsoleting it.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  I find that a lot of updates to existing projects will end up mixing like this since the factory handled object creation originally.  However, when using a powerful DI Container, you often can move away from the existing factory and replace that responsibility with the container.  Glad it's working for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Castle's [Typed Factory Facility](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md) to achieve this.

First you need to create an interface that Castle will implement:

```
public interface IFactory
{
    ICar<TEntity> CreateCar<TEntity>(ConnectionDetails connectionDetails);
    IBoat<TEntity> CreateBoat<TEntity>(ConnectionDetails connectionDetails);
    void Release(object component); // left type as object so it can release either a boat or a car
}
```

With this implementation as long as your object is registered in the container with the closed generic type as its service name castle will automatically be able to find the correct object.

Then you just need to add the facility and register your factory interface:

```
kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
kernel.Register(Component.For<IFactory>().AsFactory());
```

The article I linked at the top also covers the naming semantics of the methods in the interface as some words are given special meaning.

Comment: The problem here, is that the CreateCar and CreateBoat methods have other code in them. I did consider trying to get to this point, but couldn't quite achieve it.

Comment: Depending on what extra things you needed you can also add a custom component selector for the factory to use. That article covers this topic as well.

Comment: We have used custom component selectors a few times already, they just let you choose which type should be selected by Windsor?

Comment: Yes, there are two methods to override in this case, `GetComponentType` and `GetComponentName`  so it is admittedly not super extensible to what you could achieve, perhaps by registering different variations under different names.

Comment: Though you can actually pass in params to the factory method and they will be mapped through. I've added this to my example.

Comment: Thanks, I've ended up using a combination of these 2 answers to get this working.